# How to get calender's dates as header and get relative records form db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Can anyone please guide how to achieve this as i tried with pivot but it's not working

```
Name    |Date       |Hours
Sam     |09/01/2019 |9
Sam     |10/01/2019 |3
Sam     |10/01/2019 |4
Sam     |11/01/2019 |7
Marcos  |09/01/2019 |1
Marcos  |10/01/2019 |8
Marcos  |10/01/2019 |2
Marcos  |11/01/2019 |6.5
David   |11/01/2019 |2
David   |10/01/2019 |5
David   |09/01/2019 |3
```

Need output like
Each date respective entry shoukd have sum=10 hours
Below is the result set,displaying remaining hours for each person date wise
12 Jan is not in the db as no records are present, so for each it is showing 10 hours left

```
Name    |09/01/2019 |10/01/2019 |11/01/2019 |12/01/2019|
Sam     |1          |3          |3          |10        |
Marcos  |9          |0          |1.5        |10        |
David   |7          |5          |7          |10        |
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is not for questions about technologies or to find somebody doing the work for free (search some freelance service for that). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and how to ask.

Comment: *"i tried with pivot"* then show us what you did, so we can help. *"but it's not working"* this is not helpful: we cannot assist you without knowing **why** it did not work. Here are some good tips to ask a question like yours: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Used temp table to achieve this. Not sure how much help this for you.

```
Create table testStack (Name varchar(64), Date date, Hours INT)

insert into testStack
select 'Sam     ', '09/01/2019 ', '9'
union all select 'Sam     ', '10/01/2019 ', '3'
union all select 'Sam     ', '10/01/2019 ', '4'
union all select 'Sam     ', '11/01/2019 ', '7'
union all select 'Marcos  ', '09/01/2019 ', '1'
union all select 'Marcos  ', '10/01/2019 ', '8'
union all select 'Marcos  ', '10/01/2019 ', '2'
union all select 'Marcos  ', '11/01/2019 ', '6'
union all select 'David   ', '11/01/2019 ', '2'
union all select 'David   ', '10/01/2019 ', '5'
union all select 'David   ', '09/01/2019 ', '3'

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATE) 
                    from testStack
                    group by DATE
                    order by DATE
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')+ ', [' + CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120) + ']'


set @query = 'SELECT NAME,' + @cols + ' into testtemptable from 
             (
                select NAME, DATE, HOURS
                from testStack
            ) sourcetable
            pivot 
            (
                sum(HOURS)
                for DATE in (' + @cols + ')
            ) pivottable '

execute(@query);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', 10 - ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(DATE) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(DATE)
                    from testStack
                    group by DATE
                    order by DATE
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')+ ', ISNULL([' + CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120) + '], 10) [' + CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120) + ']'

set @query = 'SELECT NAME,' + @cols + ' from testtemptable'

execute(@query);

drop table testtemptable
DROP TABLE testStack
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have preferred that the author of the post do this part: Queries to create table and populate.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME TABLE (Name varchar(50), WorkDate datetime, hours decimal);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Sam','09/01/2019',9);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Sam','10/01/2019',3);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Sam','10/01/2019',4);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Sam','11/01/2019',7);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Marcos','09/01/2019',1);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Marcos','10/01/2019',8);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Marcos','10/01/2019',2);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('Marcos','11/01/2019',6.5);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('David','11/01/2019',2);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('David','10/01/2019',5);
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES('David','09/01/2019',3);
```

For you question, you just need to group by name, date and pivot query to transpose

```
SELECT n.name, 
      10 - SUM(n.Hours) Hours, 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), n.WorkDate, 103) AS 'WorkDate'
FROM @TABLENAME n
GROUP BY n.name , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), n.WorkDate, 103)
ORDER BY n.name
```

You can use [PIVOT QUERY](https://www.seguetech.com/sql-server-pivot-query/) to transpose columns to rows in order to get dates as headers.

Result:

```
    name    Hours   WorkDate
1   Sam     1       01/09/2019
2   Sam     3       01/10/2019
3   Sam     3       01/11/2019
4   ....
```

Try it on [SQL FIDDLE](https://rextester.com/SWBDF57335)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the next approach. Steps are:

- Generate all possible dates within range using recursion (or calendar
  table)
- Get all combinations between dates, names and calculated remaining hours
- PIVOT data

T-SQL - this is static example, if you need data for different days, you need to generate dynamic statement:

```
---------------------------
-- Table
---------------------------
CREATE TABLE #Table (
   [Name] varchar(10),
   [Date] date,
   [Hours] numeric(5, 1)
)
INSERT INTO #Table
   (Name, [Date], Hours)
VALUES
   ('Sam',     '2019-01-09', 9),
   ('Sam',     '2019-01-10', 3),
   ('Sam',     '2019-01-10', 4),
   ('Sam',     '2019-01-11', 7),
   ('Marcos',  '2019-01-09', 1),
   ('Marcos',  '2019-01-10', 8),
   ('Marcos',  '2019-01-11', 2),
   ('Marcos',  '2019-01-11', 6.5),
   ('David',   '2019-01-11', 2),
   ('David',   '2019-01-10', 5),
   ('David',   '2019-01-09', 3)

---------------------------
-- Statement
---------------------------
;WITH dates AS (
    -- Generate all possible dates within range using recursion
    SELECT CONVERT(date, '2019-01-09') AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [Date])
    FROM dates
    WHERE [Date] < CONVERT(date, '2019-01-12')
)
SELECT
   -- Non-pivoted and pivoted columns
   [Name],
   [2019-01-09] AS '2019-01-09',
   [2019-01-10] AS '2019-01-10',
   [2019-01-11] AS '2019-01-11',
   [2019-01-12] AS '2019-01-12'
FROM (
   -- SELECT statement that produces the data
   -- 1. Get all generated dates
   -- 2. CROSS APPLY them with all distinct names
   -- 3. JOIN them with calculted hours per day
   SELECT dates.[Date], names.[Name], 10 - ISNULL(hours.[Hours], 0) AS Hours
   FROM dates
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT DISTINCT Name
      FROM #Table
   ) names
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT [Name], [Date], SUM([Hours]) AS Hours
      FROM #Table
      GROUP BY [Name], [Date]
   ) hours ON (dates.[Date] = hours.[Date]) AND (names.[Name] = hours.[Name])
) p
PIVOT (
   -- Rotate data with PIVOT
   SUM ([Hours])
   FOR [Date] IN ([2019-01-09], [2019-01-10], [2019-01-11], [2019-01-12])
) AS pvt
```

Output:

```
Name    2019-01-09  2019-01-10  2019-01-11  2019-01-12
David   7.0         5.0         8.0         10.0
Marcos  9.0         2.0         1.5         10.0
Sam     1.0         3.0         3.0         10.0
```